# jQuery UI slider - Can it look like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Can a jQuery UI Slider be made to look like this? If so how?

[image: slider]

Comment: @j08691 No it is not possible in jQuery slider just with CSS. The progressed part is blue and the rest is grey. The jQuery slider uses single div for slider.

Comment: have you tried to customize it online with http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: @SKS - OK, with CSS alone no, you probably can't get that effect. Throw in some jQuery and sure, no problem (http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#colorpicker).

Comment: see my answer. but with some markup/css/js addition you can.

Comment: @j08691 True, It was range slider.. updated my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9998233/297641

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** It is possible when using [range slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#colorpicker)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/DXxa2/1/)

```
#slider {
 margin: 10px;
 height: 3px;    
}
#slider a {
    background-image: url("<!-- Your image -->") !important;
}

#slider .ui-slider-range { background-color: #58BEEA; background-image: none; }
```

It is possible to change the jQuery slider a bit like what you have, but the blue & grey part signifying the progressed area is not possible just with CSS for a regular slider.

You can take it to the extreme of adding div.. but it is too much of stuff for a simple slider.

```
#slider {
 margin: 10px;
 height: 3px;    
}
#slider a {
    background-image: url("<!-- Your image for sider-->") !important;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/DXxa2/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. By using images. The handler is an a-element, so in css set it to the height of the image of  your handler and set the image as the background-image.

That's basically everything you'll have to do.. The rest is supported by the slider plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think so. The only problem would be that radial gradient and the shape of the slider. Also, it would never work in IE. I would tell you how, but I need to do some research on the customization of sliders.

### Edit

I don't know how the JQuery UI works at all but here is the CSS I would use if they were just div, I am sure it can be used somehow:

```
/*Bar*/
#barblue, #bargrey {
height:5px;
border-radius: 2px;
background-color: deepskyblue;
border: 1px solid darkcyan;
width: 50%;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px darkcyan;
}
#bargrey {
background-color: lightgrey;
border-color: grey;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px grey;
}
/*Slider*/
#slider {
border-radius: 50px 50px 90px 90px;
border: 1px solid grey;
height: 20px;
width: 15px;
background: grey;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px grey;
}
```

For the slider you will have to use an image to get the metal look.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sander Bruggeman have said.

if you look at following mark up and css that supports it. it uses background images to render out the states of slideer. but here is how you could do it in theory.

in following mark, you add another div to support your blue path state.

```
<div class="demo">

    <div id="slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <div class="blue-path-state"></div>
        <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%; "></a>
    </div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

to update .blue-path-state, you would need to listen to change event, if you dig through documentation for slider, you can run your custom function on that event, which would update the background image of .blue-path-state to overlay path with blue background to create that blue fill, and adjust width or background-position of that blue-path-state through change event and your custom function.

for example for the update function you could do following.

```
var slider = $( ".selector" );
var blue_path = $('.blue-path-state',slider);
slider.slider({
    change: function(event, ui) {
        blue_path.css('width':slider.slider( "value" )); // set width of the blue line
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

off course, I recently made a slider like you have, basically you need to have these 3 pieces as images, the blue strip of left side that indicates the progress made so far, and the grey piece on right that shows the progress to be completed. And the slider icon will also have to be image with absolute position. Check in Firebug, the exact classes where you need to give these background images.